# Android: Dynamically added v7 preference does not have focus on Android TV

Tags: android, android-preferences

I wrote a testing app which dynamically add preference (support.v7), but the added preference does not have focus. However, dynamically added preference (v1) can have focus.

For example:
**(support.v7 example, no focus)**

```
import android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen;

public final class MySettings extends PreferenceFragment {
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("android.intent.action.MYTEST")) {
                Preference pref1 = new Preference(getPreferenceManager().getContext());
                pref1.setTitle("First");
                getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(pref1);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.my_settings); // only contains a PreferenceScreen
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.MYTEST");
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }
}
```

However, the following can have focus
**(v1 example, have focus)**

```
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceScreen;

public final class MySettings extends PreferenceFragment {
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("android.intent.action.MYTEST")) {
                Preference pref1 = new Preference(getContext());
                pref1.setTitle("First");
                getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(pref1);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.my_settings); // only contains a PreferenceScreen
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.MYTEST");
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }
}
```

**But I need to use supporting library v7 due to porting task.
How can I have focus using supporting library v7?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onResume` of your `PreferenceFragment` or `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, set a focus on the listview used to show the preferences:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // only contains a PreferenceScreen
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.my_settings); 
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.MYTEST");
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);

    // request focus on the listview
    getListView().requestFocus();
}
```

more info here :

- [getListView doc for PreferenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v14/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#getListView())
- [getListView doc for PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html#getListView())